# Also found '-(void) init'

Tags: objective-c, class, init

I built a custom class named game:

.h

```
-(void) init;
```

here I have a Also found '-(void) init'

.m

```
    -(void) init {
    [super init];
    score = 0;
    lives = 3;

    elements = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1000];
}
```

when I try to initialize a object with:

```
myGame = [[Game alloc] init];
```

I got "Multiple methods named '-init' found
So I don't know where the error is...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

init should always return (id). Change your function to the following:

.h

```
-(id) init;
```

.m

```
-(id) init {
    if((self = [super init]))
    {
        score = 0;
        lives = 3;

        elements = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1000];
    }

    return self;
}
```

Comment: The Apple Objective-C convention states that "The return type of an initializer method should be id.".